# How to continue hit testing for a specific FrameworkElement

Tags: wpf, hittest

Say that we have two superposed rectangle `r1` and `r2` where `r1.Zindex < r2.Zindex`.
`r2.IsHitTestVisible` must be `true` because `r2` has a tooltip and `r2` is visible only if the mouse is over `r1`.

With the default WPF hit testing, when the mouse is over those rectangles, `r2` is blinking because:

- when `r2` is not visible, `r1` is the topmost hit test visible element, so the mouse is over `r1` which set `r2` as visible.
- when `r2` is visible, `r1` is no longer the topmost hit test visible element, so the mouse is not considered to be over it, which in return hide `r2`.

Here is a concrete example :

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.Width = 500;
canvas.Height = 300;

Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle();
r1.Width = 200;
r1.Height = 100;
r1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
Canvas.SetLeft(r1, 100);
Canvas.SetTop(r1, 100);
canvas.Children.Add(r1);

Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle();
r2.Width = 200;
r2.Height = 100;
r2.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
Canvas.SetLeft(r2, 100);
Canvas.SetTop(r2, 100);
canvas.Children.Add(r2);

r1.IsHitTestVisible = true;
r2.IsHitTestVisible = true;
r2.ToolTip = "r2";
r2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

r1.MouseEnter += (sender, e) => r2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
r1.MouseLeave += (sender, e) => r2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

To avoid this blinking scenario and to be able to display `r2`'s tooltip, I would like to modify the default HitTesting algorithm so that :

- `r2` remains hit test visible, but does not stop the HitTest research when encountered.
- `r1` keeps the same behaviour.

Comment: Replace `r1.MouseLeave += ...` by `r2.MouseLeave += ...`

Comment: The above code is juste an example. In the real code I just can't know when this kind of configuration will occure, I can only identify `r2`-like objects.